# Merging 2 Singly Linked Lists (without Head Node)

Tags: c, merge, singly-linked-list

I have 2 Singly Linked Lists **without Head Node** :

LIST 1:   [x1->x2->.....->xn]

LIST 2:   [y1->y2->......->ym]

After merging:

if(n < m)

LIST 1:   [x1->y1->x2->y2->.....->xn->yn->y(n+1)->....->ym]

else

LIST 1:   [x1->y1->x2->y2->.....->xm->ym->x(m+1)->....->xn]

Here's my Merge function:

```
void merge(NODE *list1, NODE *list2)
{
    NODE *ptr1 = list1;
    NODE *ptr2 = list2;

    while(1)
    {
        if(ptr2 == NULL)
            break;

        if(ptr1->next == NULL)
        {
            ptr1->next = ptr2;
            display(list1);

            while(list2 != NULL)
                list2 = list2->next;

            break;
        }

        list2 = list2->next;

        ptr2->next = ptr1->next;
        ptr1->next = ptr2;

        ptr2 = list2;
        ptr1 = (ptr1->next)->next;

        display(list1);
    }
}
```

**But after executing it in main function, LIST 2 should've been empty, but it's not.**

For example:

LIST 1:    [1-> 2-> 3]

LIST 2:    [5-> 6-> 7]

After merging:

LIST 1:    [1-> 5-> 2-> 6-> 3-> 7]

LIST 2:    [5-> 2-> 6-> 3-> 7] (This should've been empty)

Please Explain!

**Edit :**

**Sample Output :**

----------[List 1]----------

Enter an element (-123 to exit): 1

[  LIST:    1  ]

Enter an element (-123 to exit): 2

[  LIST:    1  2  ]

Enter an element (-123 to exit): -123

----------[List 2]----------

Enter an element (-123 to exit): 5

[  LIST:    5  ]

Enter an element (-123 to exit): 6

[  LIST:    5  6  ]

Enter an element (-123 to exit): 7

[  LIST:    5  6  7  ]

Enter an element (-123 to exit): 8

[  LIST:    5  6  7  8  ]

Enter an element (-123 to exit): -123

[  LIST:    1  5  2  ]

[  LIST:    1  5  2  6  7  8  ]

----------[Merged List]----------

[  LIST:    1  5  2  6  7  8  ]

[  LIST:    5  2  6  7  8  ]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide an [MCVE]

Comment: What makes you think that "LIST 2" should be empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason for List2 to be empty:

List 2 is not literally a list, merely a pointer to the first element of the second list, which after merge becomes the second element of the complete list.

In memory, there is only a single list `[1->5->2-> 6-> 3-> 7]`, with the pointer `list1` pointing to its first element and `list2` pointing to the second one.

Thus, when you print your `list1` it will print the list starting form 1, while when you print `list2` it will print the list starting from 5

Comment: But I have incremented list2 to point to next node in each iteration of while loop, so won't it point to NULL after the last iteration?

Comment: The pointers are passed by value to the merge function, basically, you only took a copy and incremented it, not affecting the pointer outside the scope of the function

Comment: Okay... Got it! Thanks for the reply brother! :)

Answer (score 0):

Pointers are pointers. They just point at things. It's perfectly valid to have a pointer that points in the middle of a linked list. This way, one list can be a subset of another list. As pointed out in the comment, this is not strange behavior from a merge function.

Howver, if you want to do this:
In order to "make list 2 empty" you could just dereference it after the call. Like this:

```
merge(list1, list2);
list2 = NULL;
```

If you want to do it within the function, you could use pointer to pointers:

```
void merge(NODE **list1, NODE **list2)
{
    NODE *ptr1 = *list1;
    NODE *ptr2 = *list2;    
 // Do stuff
    if(blabla) 
        **list1 = NULL;
    else
        **list2 = NULL;
}
```

and then call merge like this:

```
merge(&list1, &list1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I appreciate your efforts :)

Comment: Nope. Just one.

Comment: Your answer helped me but didn't answer the question